# How I can slice a []strings matrix based on column value in golang without hardcoding slice indexes?

Tags: go, matrix, slice

I want to split text in a matrix based on space character, so I can store each character into a []string for later usage.

For that I am slicing a matrix based on space character in column over the 9 rows * 20 columns matrix. If column x all the rows have space then it means one charatcer has ended.

I have been able to figure out how to slice it manually, by trieal and error method and looking for starting and ending column: character[0:3] for 1, character[4:12] for 2 and character[12:19] for 3 but haven't been able to figure it out how to do it without hardcoding the columns indexes for the character.

It should store columns with characters into a result []string and look for another column till space for another charater. How should I condition for range loop so it does as described?

input from example00.txt file:

```
                    
 _   ____    _____  
/ | |___ \  |___ /  
| |   __) |   |_ \  
| |  / __/   ___) | 
|_| |_____| |____/
```

Code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var readFlags = flag.String("reverse", "example.txt", "read file from flag")

func main() {

    flag.Parse()
    args := flag.Args()

    const usage = "Usage: go run . [OPTION]\n\nEX: go run . --reverse=<fileName>"
    if len(args) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(usage)
        return
    }

    input, _ := os.ReadFile("test/" + *readFlags)
    slice := strings.Split(string(input), "\n")

    var result []string
    for _, character := range slice {
        if len(character) > 0 {
            // fmt.Println(string(character[0:3]))
            column := character[4:12]
            // fmt.Println(string(character[12:19]))
            result = append(result, column)

        }
    }

    for _, value := range result {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}

// go run . --reverse=example00.txt
```

Output for example value fmt.Println(value)

```
% go run . --reverse=example00.txt
        
 ____   
|___ \  
  __) | 
 / __/  
|_____|
```

Hope my explenation makes sense. Any help/guidance would be really appraciated.

Also if there is a good resource about slicing a matrix based on certain x conditions on rows or columns please point me there. :)

Comment: Make a list (or set) S containing the indexes of all spaces in the first line. For each line starting with the second, remove all indexes from S where there is no space at the corresponding location in the line. S now contains your break points.

Comment: Thank's @Peter. Will try to do like you reccommended!